# (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Tags: node.js

I am a newbie to Nodjs. setMaxListeners(0) didnt work for me. I get this error on subsequent connections to the database (mysql). 
All I have in my code is:

```
var http= require(), etc;
http.createServer(
function (req, res) { ... }).listen(8888);
```

There are many switch cases within the function with forms being submitted & sql queries executed between the different switch cases

Comment: We need to see some code, where do you `setMaxListeners` and where do you add listeners ?

Comment: Feel free to post the code and post also the error message.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing some code first, you might just take a look to see if you are using enter `.on` handlers instead of `.once` handlers.

If you are creating many `.on` event handlers, they may not be released once execution of the request/response cycle stops.

Try converting some or most of your `.on` handlers to use `.once` instead, and see how it goes.